# How can I speed up a simple rails database query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4.2.11.1, on ruby 2.6.3

I have had extremely slow requests using rails, so I benchmarked my code and found the main culprit. The majority of the slowdown happens at the database call, where I select a single row from a table in the database. I have tried a few different versions of the same idea

Using this version

```
Rails.logger.info Benchmark.measure{
  result = Record.find_by_sql(['SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition']).first.column
}
```

the rails output says that the sql takes 54.5ms, but the benchmark prints out 0.043427   0.006294   0.049721 (  1.795859), and the total request takes 1.81 seconds. When I run the above sql directly in my postgres terminal, it takes 42ms.

Obviously the problem is not that my sql is slow. 42 milliseconds is not noticeable. But 1.79 seconds is way too slow, and creates a horrible user experience.

I did some reading and came to the conclusion that the slowdown was caused by rails' object creation (which seems weird, but apparently that can be super slow) so I tried using pluck to minimize the number of objects created:

```
Rails.logger.info Benchmark.measure{
    result = Record.where(condition).pluck(column).first
}
```

Now rails says that the sql took 29.3ms, and the benchmark gives 0.017989   0.006119   0.024108 (  0.713973)
The whole request takes 0.731 seconds. This is a huge improvement, but 0.7 seconds is still a bad slowdown and still undermines the usability of my application.

What am I doing wrong? It seems insane to me that something so simple should have such a huge slowdown. If this is just how rails works I can't imagine that anyone uses it for serious applications!

Comment: It's hard to tell from the generic way in which you've presented it. How many columns are in the row? Is the object being created unusually large?

Comment: Also why are you using where if you only want the first one? You are asking it to search the entire DB for matches, and return them all, then give the first.

Comment: @Beartech it looks like the table has about 50 columns. I don't think that's super large. Rails outputs for me exactly what sql statement it runs, and for the second one it does `SELECT "table"."column" FROM "table" WHERE condition`

Comment: So it is not returning them all. It is filtering them out at the sql level automatically

Comment: Also what system are you running this entire app on? I develop on my 6 year old laptop and rails can slow down if I push it, but it flies in production on Heroku. Is this your production server? What are you comparing this to?

Comment: I am doing the benchmarking on localhost dev server, on my 2019 macbook pro. I'm not going to edit the production code to add benchmarking, but the same request to the production server takes 0.3 seconds. My dev server is taking 1.3 seconds at the fastest

Comment: Okay, I turned on my production version locally and it is now slightly faster. About 0.6 seconds for the pluck version and 1.1 seconds for the find_by_sql version

Comment: You still haven't said what kind of results you are expecting. This is a web app, no? What kind of benchmarks are you getting for the actual request/response/page load?

Comment: @Beartech I would prefer to have response times that are fast enough to not be noticeable for the user. Below a tenth of a second would probably work. A bit of a lag because of the network is one thing, but I imagine the server itself should not be causing a noticeable slowdown.

Comment: The server supports a web and a mobile app. I'm using Postman to test the requests. Just now I timed a few requests to our development server, and I got between 1 and 2.5 seconds for each one

Comment: Hmm, when I run several requests to the production server it appears to be much faster. Between 76 and 300 ms. Including network time, that's probably not too slow. Could this just be an issue with my production server having super slow object creation?

Answer (score 1):

`find_by_sql` executes a custom SQL query against your database and returns all the results.

That means all the records in your database are returned and instanciated. Only then do you pick the first one from that array by calling `first` on the results.

When you call `first` on a ActiveRecord::Relation, it will add a limit to your query and pick only that, which is the behavior you want.

That means you should be limiting the query yourself:

```rb
  result = Record.find_by_sql(['SELECT column FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 1']).first.column
```

I'm pretty sure that your request will be fast then as ruby doesn't need to instanciate all the result rows.

Comment: I'd add `ORDER BY id ASC` in order to get a more predictable result.

Comment: The condition is unique for each row, so it will only return one record anyway. I just now tried it with limit 1 built in, and it is still 1.7 seconds. The version with pluck was much faster

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, not sure why you ask for all the matches if you just want the first one.

If I do:

```
 Rails.logger.info Benchmark.measure{
   result = User.where(email: 'foo@bar.com').pluck(:email).first 
 }

(9.6ms)  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  [["email", "foo@bar.com"]]
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fc2ce4b7998 @label="", @real=0.6364280000561848,     @cstime=0.00364, @cutime=0.000661, @stime=0.1469640000000001, @utime=0.1646029999999996, @total=0.3158679999999997>

 Rails.logger.info Benchmark.measure{
   result = User.where(email: 'foo@bar.com').limit(1).pluck(:email) 
 }

 (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users"."email" FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "foo@bar.com.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
#<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fc2ce4cd838 @label="", @real=0.004004000045824796, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0005539999999997214, @utime=0.0013550000000002171, @total=0.0019089999999999385>
```

Rails also does cashing. If you run your query again it should be faster the second time. How complex is your `where` condition?  That might be part of it.

Comment: The where condition is a simple equality check on a column, `where column = option`, and it is a unique column. So this query should always return a single row.

Comment: I tried using limit(1) as you suggest, and it appears to be taking about 1 second on average.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: Is the column indexed in the DB?

Comment: Pretty sure it is. But like i said in the op, the sql call is super quick when i run it manually

Comment: Yes the DB is fast. As you suspected there is some cost to taking a DB row and turning it into a Ruby object. I don't have a standard to compare yours data to. If a page takes more than 2-3 seconds to load I try to make it faster.

Comment: Maybe use some of the info here: https://pawelurbanek.com/slow-rails-queries